# Why don't all (default) certificates from raspbian version 10 ("buster") pass the "openssl verify ..."-test?

Tags: ssl, raspberry-pi, certificate, raspbian

... Or, more specifically: Why does one certificate contain a "not yet valid" date-stamp?

This is the version I am running: https://pastebin.com/2GrWJrzs

This is the output while verifying all certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/: https://pastebin.com/z9m8sh1F

The specific part I am wondering (MOSTLY) about, is this:

```
CN = raspberrypi
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
CN = raspberrypi
error 9 at 0 depth lookup: certificate is not yet valid
error ./98a46391: verification failed
```

... and also this:

```
CN = raspberrypi
error 18 at 0 depth lookup: self signed certificate
CN = raspberrypi
error 9 at 0 depth lookup: certificate is not yet valid
error ./ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem: verification failed
```

Sidenote that shouldn't matter (in my opinion anyway) is: I am checking the validity from an Xubuntu 20.04 install and **NOT** from the raspberry itself (which I haven't even tried yet).

The only modifications I've done on the raspberry install is to patch the vulnerable OpenSSL client with this patch (compiled from source & the source was downloaded thru apt-get): https://github.com/openssl/openssl/commit/eb563247aef3e83dda7679c43f9649270462e5b1

... So what's going on here?

**Edit with some additional information**: The pre-installed **AND ALSO** the updated/upgraded (by using commandline "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssl-client") OpenSSL client is version 1.1.1d and as I pointed out above in the original post it is susceptible to a DOS-attack (source: https://www.openssl.org/news/vulnerabilities.html#2020-1967), which ain't anything any **user** wants.

I was planning on running a tiny webserver on this raspberry pi (model 3B+ from 2017), utilizing RAM-resilient shells with access to root-accounts through the use of qemu-kvm & a very size-optimized kernel + (shared) initramfs (read-only marked) image. So, this was kind of a baby-steps procedure to check the validity of the host system itelf (ie. the raspbian install), since that is what handles the connections from the clients, it is anyhow the most critical point in this project. The system was not intented for SSL/TLS on the HTTPd (self-written), but the SSH-connection on the other hand: Yes, I do think that users would like to feel safe, even if they are running in a virtual environment inside a real environment. :)

PS. I am a programmer, not a crypto-expert. :)

***EDIT (2020-08-20 23:42):*** Really? Noone know why, or any scenario this would happen? Could someone at least please verify this information by downloading & verifying a Raspbian version 10 ("buster") image, write it to an SD-card and just run the following command in the mounted "rootfs"-partition of the sd-card: "openssl verify ./etc/ssl/certs/*" from a host system? This test should also be possible by mounting the image itself and then run "openssl verify" on the "etc/ssl/certs/" directory through the use of loop-devices.

Anyhow, any suggestions would be of great respect and loyalty. Am almost in the process of purging most of the raspberry + all of my other systems soon enough if this doesn't get resolved.

*(Estimated waste of time is about 3-40 depending on download-speed + burning/writing it to an SD-card, the rest is really an estimated 1 minute or so).*

Comment: Is it possible that the date/time on Raspbian is set incorrectly? Or the checking computer?

Comment: No. Have connected the raspberry to ethernet for updating as a first step. But besides that, yes, I have on my host system (one time) changed the date to highest possible just for the lulz (but with the system completely offline of course and then rebooted). I just created a file named A_FILE_FROM_THE_FUTURE with the highest possible date on a 64bit system. But that install was not this host install. EDIT: Tho, would'nt that make the certificate be "expired" instead of "not yet valid" anyways? :) PS: Did not know how to edit a comment, so I deleted the previous one and replaced it with this.

Comment: I removed the faulty certiificates, but one remains and I get this error: unable to load certificate
140516891563328:error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:../crypto/pem/pem_lib.c:745:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

(it has no name?)

Comment: The comment I wanted to post exceeds the limit on comments, so I edited my original post. You'll find it with bold + cursive text at the mark "EDIT (2020-08-20 23:42):".